# NodeJS setInterval does not always seem to fire?

Tags: node.js

I am relying on a setInterval to be fired in my application. It tells each socket that the server is still responding and alive a `heartbeat`.

```
clients.push(socket); // I store each socket here.

/**
* TCP Socket Heartbeat
**/
setInterval(function () {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
         client.write("{\"type\":\"heartbeat\", \"msg\": \"HELO\"}\n");
    }); 
}, 10000);
```

When the client has not received a heartbeat from the server for the last 30 seconds it goes offline and tried to reconnect.

For some reason after the server has been running for a few hours it seems to stop sending some of these heartbeats because i can see clients going offline due to inactivity, which tells me that they cannot have received the heartbeat.

Any ideas whats wrong here?

Comment: I wouldn't blame `setInterval` for that. To be honest, I have never found any problems like setInterval not executing an action. The issue which you experience, might be related to the `clients` array e.g. some clients may _disappear_ (for any reasons) from that list. I would suggest logging execution of `setInterval` and  details for each client. That can produce large amount of data but then with a small application processing that data you could find out the root cause of the issue. Also it would be worth adding more information about `clients` implementation (library etc.).

Comment: your `setInterval` purpose seems pointless, socket.io already has a heartbeat mechanism build in it, to determinate status of clients. if you server fails for some reason, client-side code should handle reconnections and notification until the server is up and running again.